# Performing a mathematical operation when cells are equal

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to add all values in column E sheet 1 when cell A and B in sheet 1 is equal to cell A and B in sheet 2. What excel formula is the best to use?

Comment: '=SUMIFS('DELIVERY RECORD'!$F$2:$F,$A$2:$A,'DELIVERY RECORD'!$D$2:$D,$D$2:$D,'DELIVERY RECORD'!$E$2:$E)'  
I used this formula, but it doesn't update the cell value if i input the same data.

Comment: Kindly include at least a screenshot of data in your post above.